# Custom column type with column options implied

Tags: scala, slick

I've got a large number of Slick tables with an `ID` column defined as

```
def id = column[Int]("ID", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc, O DBType "INT UNSIGNED")
```

and I'm wondering if there is a way to create a custom `IDPK` type that would somehow "imply" the usage of the various options shown above, e.g.

```
case class IDPK(id: Int) extends AnyVal

def id = column[IDPK]("ID")
  // O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc, O DBType "INT UNSIGNED" are all implied
```

I realize I could make a convenience function along the lines of `def makeIDPK = column[Int]("ID", .....)` but my question is about whether or not a type can be made to imply certain column options.

I've noticed that if I run `show create table <tablename>` there are options that I did not explicitly state, e.g. `NOT NULL` for non-Option columns, or `DEFAULT NULL` for Option columns. Because of this, I have hope for a "yes" answer, but I was unable to find something like this while looking through the Slick documentation.

Comment: `show create table` is going to be misleading here, since most databases have defaults for all of their settings, and will add them even if Slick doesn't.

Answer (score -1):

you could define a function that receives type and creates a column.  Something like:

```
def makeColumn[T](name: String): Column[Int] = 
  column[Int](name, O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc, O DBType "INT UNSIGNED")

def id = makeColumn("id")
```

Comment: How is this not exactly what the OP says they're _not_ asking for?